# How to align a paragraph (justify) whith Itext?

Tags: itext, text-justify

I have 2 lines and I want to align (justify) them.

I have this code:

```
    Paragraph p=new Paragraph(ANC,fontFootData);
    p.setLeading(1, 1);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    document.add(p);


    Paragraph p2=new Paragraph(RUTTEL,fontFootData);
    p2.setLeading(1, 1);
    p2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    document.add(p2);
```

where ANC and RUTTEL are string, but they not be align.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: How long are those strings? Maybe you're looking for ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL instead of ALIGN_JUSTIFIED. In any case: alignment works for us, there's no reason it shouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 5):

For a one line use ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL, more than one line use ALIGN_JUSTIFIED.

Comment: just want to add api reference here http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/ ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL Does the same as ALIGN_JUSTIFIED but the last line is also spread out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using for C#, then:

```
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
```